# Flask sessions, where are the cookies stored?

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask

I'm learning flask and want to understand how sessions work. 
Apparently the server stores a signed cookie on the client browser. 
I have done this process using

```
sessions['mycookie'] = 'mycookievalue'
```

But I'm unable to find the cookie on the browser. I normally list cookies on the browser using chrome developer tools and running the command:

```
document.cookie
```

This works when I set a cookie but nothing comes up when I set it through sessions.

Comment: Flask stores a session id in the browser with the KEY 'session'

Comment: @HassanMehmood: the default implementation stores *all session data* in a (signed) cookie.

Answer (score 14):

The Flask session cookie has the [`httponly` flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) set, making it invisible from JavaScript.

It is otherwise a normal, regular cookie so it is still stored in the browser cookie store; you should still be able to see it in your browser's developer tools.

You can set the `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` option to `False` if you want to be able to access the cookie value from JavaScript code. From the [*Builtin Configuration Values* section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#builtin-configuration-values):

> `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`
>   controls if the cookie should be set with the httponly flag. Defaults to *True*.

The cookie contains all your session data, serialised using JSON (with tagging support for a wider range of Python types), together with a cryptographic signature that makes sure the data can't be tampered with securely.

If you disable the `httponly` protection, any JS code could still decode and read all your session data. Even if it can't change those values, that could still be very interesting to malicious code. Imagine a XSS bug in your site being made worse because the JS code could just read a CSRF token used to protect a web form straight from the session.

Comment: Martijn, thanks for your response. Yes this makes sense. I was able to see the cookie after going in to chrome settings.

Comment: @Martijn Is the only difference between the cookie created by Flask session vs the "regular" cookie you can assign to a response object in Flask just the data stored therein? Is it better to use session's cookie vs creating a cookie and appending to response object via  response.set_cookie(key/value) ? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#cookies

Comment: @Malvin9000 the difference is that Flask has solved the issue of how to serialise data structures for you, as well as taken care of data integrity. You can do all that yourself and store directly in a cookie but why have a dog and bark yourself? Unless you need to share the cookie with other systems, I'd stick to the session.

Answer (score 9):

I am finding this question 3 years and 8 months later because I have an interest in the event it is modified or spoofed, to ensure my backend is able to tell the difference.

Using chrome, use F12, select Application tab, underneath Storage go to Cookies. Under cookies you'll find the webpage, select it and the right side will populate and assuming you have done something to create your session cookie, it will be there. You will notice that the value is encrypted.

[Picture showing the location of session cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj3Yh.png)

Comment: Thanks for the pic :)

Answer (score 1):

sessions are meant for server use only. That is why it is hidden and encrypted for the client. 
If you want to set a cookie which can be used by client/browser. You can just set a normal cookie instead of a secure cookie (like session).

You can set cookies by modifying response.

```
def home_page():
   resp = make_response(...)
   resp.set_cookie('my_cookie', 'cookie_value')
   return resp
```

**document.cookie** on browser will give you *mycookie=cookie_value*